# How much current can a 74HC00 supply?

Tags: digital-logic

I'm trying to figure out what kind of current a single logic gate can supply. I'm looking at this datasheet:

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc00.pdf

I see in section 6.1 it says "I<sub>O</sub> = ±25 mA", but that's the section on "absolute maximums". In particular, the device isn't guaranteed to *work* at that level, it's just guaranteed to not immediately break. (It's not even guaranteed that it won't break; just that it won't break *straight away*.)

Section 6.3, "recommended conditions", doesn't seem to say anything about current at all. (I'm assuming that current is denoted by symbols containing "I".)

Section 6.5 has "I<sub>I</sub>" (input current?) in nano-amps (...so, the inputs draw really small current?). It also lists "I<sub>CC</sub>" (total chip package current?) which is only in nano-amps. Presumably the maximum output current must be smaller than this. (?)

In short, I don't see the number I'm looking for anywhere on the datasheet. Am I being blind or something?

I'd particularly like to know what the maximum allowable fan-out is.

Comment: If you happen to be using it at 5 V, section 1, "Features", states "±4-mA Output Drive at 5 V".

Comment: And the second listed feature is "Outputs Can Drive Up to 10 LSTTL Loads". Or are you looking for the fan-out to 74HC-series chips?

Comment: *I'd particularly like to know what the maximum allowable fan-out is.* Sure but note that the fan-out is not simply the max output current (4mA) divided by the input current (nano amps). The fan-out is **strongly** related to the frequency of your signals. My guess: at 100 Hz you can assume a fan-out of one 100 or more. But at 10 MHz expect to be able to only drive a few gates (less than 5) properly. Fan out is related to dis/charging inputs which happens more often at high frequencies.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Oh, really? I just kind of *assumed* that discrete logic gates only go up to ~5 Hz or so.

Comment: *I just kind of assumed that discrete logic gates only go up to ~5 Hz* Why would you assume that? Maybe you should do a bit more research before assuming anything. Also in electronics (or engineering in general): just an "I don't know" is much better than making wrong assumptions. At 5 Hz maximum logic gates would be pretty useless for many applications.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Well, I came to Stack Exchange to learn things, so...

Comment: *I came to Stack Exchange to learn things* That is **excellent** and **awesome**. Actually it is the same for me even though I have years of experience in electronics, there's always something new to learn. And I share my knowledge where I can.

Comment: Speed: that datasheet claims a 10ns propagation delay through the gate. That puts an absolute theoretical maximum frequency of 100MHZ using them - realistically much lower. I'd expect to be able to put a 10MHz square wave through them and get something strongly resembling it on the other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The V<sub>OL</sub>/V<sub>OH</sub> specifications show how large the worst-case voltage drop can be at the specified current. You can try to draw larger currents, up to the absolute maximum rating, but then there is no longer a guarantee about the voltage drop.

For smaller currents, the output transistors (MOSFETs) behave like a resistor, so you can just interpolate the worst-case voltage drop.

The application note [Input and Output Characteristics of Digital Integrated Circuits at 5-V Supply Voltage](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/szza008) shows typical (not guaranteed) values for the voltage drop:

[image: 74HC output voltage vs. output current]

The application note [HCMOS Design Considerations](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/scla007) says:

> High-speed CMOS can support up to 10 LS loads from a single standard output […]
>   From the dc values in the individual data sheets, the fan-out of high-speed CMOS devices is unlimited for all practical purposes.
>   However, from an ac point of view, there is a definite limit to the fan-out. The limiting constraint is the input rise time.
>   [… Lots of math] indicates that the maximum fan-out of high-speed CMOS devices is approximately 505.

Comment: Whichever way you slice it, it seems the answer is 4 mA...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this datasheet does not have a plot of the decrease in output voltage with increasing output current.  However, section 8.3 restates the 4 mA figure, so I would take that as a recommended upper limit for continuous operation.

Note that at 4 mA, the output voltage will *not* be 5 V when sourcing or 0 V when sinking.  This is covered in section 6.5

Comment: The voltage will be lower, but presumably still in the range that other gate inputs will still register it as high, right?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid It's up to you to compare the Voh/Vol of the 74HC00 to the Vih/Vil of the "other gate inputs" to make sure they are compatible. If the other gates are also HC series gates with the same supply voltage then you are probably OK, but, again, don't make assumptions.